# "the chosen operation is not currently available"

Tags: android, sdk, wear-os

To update on werable device I followed [Install the Android Wear System Image](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html)

For eclipse as suggest I choose **Android SDK Manager** from **Window Menu** and here it's giving message "the chosen operation is not currently available".

Any suggestion how can handle this case and update SDK?

Regards

Comment: You need to update latest sdk to 22.6

Comment: yes..before it was giving error...I restart editor...n it allowing to update with version 22.3..but not showing any update for 22.6?

Comment: In Eclipse, go to Help -> Check for Updates and update ADT plugin for Eclipse to 22.6.1

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with updating the sdks.

Problem is that Eclipse 'for some reason' did not make the android 'plugin', which can happen sometimes when eclipse is not properly closed.

*Restarting eclipse and waiting to be sure that all dependencies are loaded*, solve the problem.